Does green transparent glass reflect green light?
I have learnt that green transparent glass only allow green light to pass through, but if that's the case why do green transparent glass appeared green in our eyes when it reflected other light and absorb only green light? Thank you.

Because it doesn't absorb green light and doesn't reflect other light.
"Pass through" is not quite the correct expression. Light is absorbed by atoms along the way and then re-emitted. Atoms emit light in all directions, including back. That's why you see green glass as green from all sides.
Light of any other color is absorbed completely and not re-emitted.

Well, the last sentence is not correct: other wavelengths are re-emitted as well but much less than green.

I quite agree with the answer.
The emission/absorption of light by/from an atom is associated with the structure of electrons within it.
This is a function of the wave-to-wave interaction of photon and electron. Note, that the fundamental particles have been ascertained to be field (wavey). Based on the atomic structure, the light absorption/emission manifest from these interactions. Thus in a green glass, this interaction produces a green spectrum of light, hence we observe greenness in all directions.
An interesting observation green leaf, the green light is reflected and the rest of the spectrum is absorbed by the atomic structure.
